# How to create dependent attributes in magento admin in create new attribute

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes

As there any way in magento where i can create dependent attributes like color depends on size ?.

i am added one dropdown box in magento attribute under "Manage Options (values of your attribute)" but no idea how to get size attribute value in dropdownbox

please see the my attache screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want this as a backend feature, then the answer is no.

If you want this as a frontend feature, then the answer is yes. This can be done using configurable products.

If you create a variant that is avaiable in blue and in sizes small, medium, large, and then some further variants with the colour being red, but sizes only in medium and large. This way, when you select the colour red, in the size dropdown, you'll only see medium and large as options, not small.